# Seasonal component of STL decomposition looks like the original data

Tags: time-series, seasonality, decomposition

I am doing STL decomposition on [Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/neuromusic/avocado-prices). Below is just example for one region. I have summed up the values for type (conventional, organic). So data is grouped on date and region.

My question is the seasonality component doesn't seem like seasonality. It seems like entire series. This is not specific to this region (Albany). Other regions also show similar result. Can someone explain what is happening with STL decomposition?

```
df_avocado = pd.read_csv("avocado.csv")

df_avocado['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_avocado['Date'])
df_avocado = df_avocado.sort_values(by=['Date']).reset_index(drop=True)


df_avocado = df_avocado.rename(columns={'Date': 'week', 'Total Volume': 'quantity'})


df_avocado = df_avocado.groupby(by=['region', 'week'], as_index=False).agg({'quantity': sum})
df_avocado['week_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df_avocado['week'])
df_avocado = df_avocado.sort_values(by=['week']).reset_index(drop=True)

df_avocado = df_avocado.loc[:, ['region', 'week', 'quantity']]


x = []
for reg in df_avocado['region'].unique():
    print(reg)
    
    df_temp = df_avocado.loc[df_avocado['region']==reg, ['region', 'week', 'quantity']].copy()
    
    ser_df_temp = df_temp.set_index('week')
    stl_df_temp = STL(ser_df_temp['quantity'])
    result_df_temp = stl_df_temp.fit()
    seasonality_df_temp, trend_df_temp, resid_df_temp = result_df_temp.seasonal, result_df_temp.trend, result_df_temp.resid

    df_temp['quantity'] = resid_df_temp.values
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

    plt.subplot(4,1,1)
    plt.plot(ser_df_temp['quantity'])
    plt.title(f'Original Series {(reg)}', fontsize=16)


    plt.subplot(4,1,2)
    plt.plot(trend_df_temp)
    plt.title('Trend', fontsize=16)

    plt.subplot(4,1,3)
    plt.plot(seasonality_df_temp)
    plt.title('Seasonal', fontsize=16)

    plt.subplot(4,1,4)
    plt.plot(resid_df_temp)
    plt.title('Residual', fontsize=16)

    plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: If you included your code, it would be easier to tell what is happening.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577339

Comment: I think I have deleted the duplicate question. if not please let me know. When I submitted for reopening the question for review after adding code there was no change in the interface anywhere on the web page that indicated that the closed question is again gone for review. I have added code as well.

Comment: Yes, the other question has been deleted.

Comment: If this question follows the quality standards can this question be reopened ?

Comment: Yes, it can. I have voted for reopening and someone else did, too. You need one more vote (I think the norm is 3). Unfortunately, getting the 3 votes is not easy, given that most of the questions on this site do not get all that many views...